# how to disable a <div> after clicking 2 times per day per user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

i want to know how can i make this 
only clickable 2 times per day for per users and how can i make this ad to be open in new window when users will click on it

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

  <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-" data-ad-slot="" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to maintain the record . Probably cannot be possible only with front end

Comment: how to do that help me

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickedAd = [null, null];
document.getElementById("myCheck").onclick = function(){
clickedAd.forEach(function(idx, ele){
    if(ele == null){
        ele[idx] = "something";
    }
}
if(clickedAd[1] !== null){
    document.getElementById("id-to-hide").style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(function(){
        clickedAd = [null, null];
    }, 86400000);
} else {
document.getElementById("id-to-hide").style.display = "block";
}
};
```

something like this should do the thing

Comment: how to implement this bro?

Comment: just throw in a javascript file, or make <script></script> tags and write it between them

Comment: what are you trying to block exactly?

Comment: i want to replace this <div class="thumbnai">  
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- best -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1424926498442299"
     data-ad-slot="2174407566"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>                                                                                   with <div class="box">Please Try Again After 24hr</div>        after 2 click per visiter per day